# argparse, python3, can't use parsed file as file

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

So I need to parse .txt file as argument to my script. And then split it by lines, turn it into list and then print it.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('textA', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs=1, default='textA.txt')
args = parser.parse_args()

textA = args.textA.read().split('\n')
print(textA)
```

So but it's ending up with `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'` in console

I think I just don't know how to parse file proparly

Sorry about my english grammar

Comment: Include a `print(args)` in your debugging code so you have clear idea of what the parser produced.  That would show you that it produced a one element list, not just an opened file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `narg` parameter is the cause of the problem.

This is the documentation that explains the usage of this parameter
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#nargs

1. If you wish this arg to be optional and defaults to 'textA.txt', you should use `nargs="?"` in this case.
2. If you wish to make this a mandatory field, change `args.textA.read()` to `args.textA[0].read()` and leave `nargs=1` as is